# WebGL: What is faster?

Tags: opengl-es, directx, glsl, webgl

What is faster in WebGL?

**once:**
   create 1000 shaders for 1000 objects and set uniforms to them

**every frame:**
   bind shaders when rendering them

Or

**once:**
   create 10 shaders for 1000 objects

**every frame:**
   bind shaders + update uniforms according to objects?

I know I can write test on it. But I feel that someone surely thought about it before me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Most probably the second option. Changing shaders is (in most cases) a very expensive operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's helpful to remember that the [Graphics Pipeline](http://openglinsights.com/pipeline.html) is an actual pipeline typically implemented in hardware.  You get to configure the pipeline by assigning shaders and setting uniforms, and then you get to activate the pipeline (by calling `drawElements` or one of its friends).  This essentially loads a pile of input data into the start of the pipeline, and kicks off a process that is highly parallel.  For example, in the middle of a run, some early vertices will have made it through the vertex shader and rasterizer, and the resulting fragments are being shaded, while other vertices are still back at the vertex shader stage being transformed.  The different sections of the pipeline are all doing their thing to the data flowing by.

After you kick off this process, the CPU is free to do other stuff while the pipeline runs.  But, if you want to reconfigure the pipeline, such as by changing shaders or altering uniforms, the CPU will block your thread and wait for the pipeline to be completely done to the last pixel.

This means you want to avoid stopping and restarting the pipeline, to the extent possible.  So the usual strategy is batching:  Get as much work done as possible in a single draw call, with a single set of uniforms.  That way, you exploit the parallel nature of the pipeline to the best extent possible in your app.

[image: Pipeline image courtesy OpenGLInsights.com]

Answer (score 1):

Changing shaders is expensive (it invalidates the instruction cache), updating uniforms cheap (it just updates values in a register file).